# Is there a way to extract a common interface from multiple classes in C#

Tags: c#, codegen

I've got some code generated from an XSD, one of the properties is an array that can be one of 7 different classes, all these classes share some fields so I would like to create an interface so I can iterate over the array and access the 'tpl' property without having to do a huge switch statement and casting.

I've done this manually for now just for the 'tpl' property but **I was wondering if there was a tool or way to paste all the classes into something and it would identify the common properties and generate an interface for me?**

My Google fu is only comming up with things that will extract an interface from a single class or keep a class and interface in sync.

```cs
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("DT", typeof(DT2))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("IP", typeof(IP2))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("OPDT", typeof(OPDT2))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("OPIP", typeof(OPIP2))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("OPOR", typeof(OPOR2))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("OR", typeof(OR2))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PP", typeof(PP2))]
        public object[] Items {
            get {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to write this myself, wasn't too hard after all.

Created a new Console App, added my other project as a reference. Add each Class to the list of lists then intersect each list with the previous to remove any items that don't exist in all Classes.

It's a bit rough and could be extended to public methods, and possibly a filter on the reflection to make sure the properties are actually public as well.

Would welcome any comments on how to improve it.

```cs
var listOfLists = new List<List<Properties>>();

listOfLists.Add(GetPropertyList<Class1>());
listOfLists.Add(GetPropertyList<Class2>());
listOfLists.Add(GetPropertyList<Class3>());


var output = Intersect(listOfLists);
WriteInterfaceOut(output);


static List<Properties>? Intersect(List<List<Properties>> listOfLists)
{
    List<Properties>? outputList = null;
    foreach (var item in listOfLists)
    {
        if (outputList == null)
        {
            outputList = item;
            continue;
        }

        outputList = outputList.Intersect(item, new Properties.Comparer()).ToList();
    }
    return outputList;
}

static void WriteInterfaceOut(List<Properties>? list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("public interface IRenameMe \r\n{");
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"    public {item.TypeName} {item.Name} {{get; set;}}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("}");
    Console.ReadKey();

}

static List<Properties> GetPropertyList<T>()
{
    var list = new List<Properties>();
    PropertyInfo[] myPropertyInfo;

    myPropertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    for (int i = 0; i < myPropertyInfo.Length; i++)
    {
        list.Add(new Properties() { Name = myPropertyInfo[i].Name, TypeName = myPropertyInfo[i].PropertyType });
    }   
    return list;
}

public class Properties
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type TypeName { get; set; }


    public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Properties>
    {
        public bool Equals(Properties? x, Properties? y)
        {
            return x?.Name == y?.Name && x?.TypeName == y?.TypeName;
        }

        public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] Properties obj)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                var hash = 17;
                hash = hash * 23 + obj.Name.GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 23 + obj.TypeName.GetHashCode();
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }

}
```